# AS3 different image when a button is in use

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an application for kind of like a homemade microsoft paint made completely in AS3, I am not that advanced in actionscript, but I will ask you my question and thank you in advance!

So I have buttons, each button is a drawing tool, and I want the icon for the drawing tool(button) to be something different than when it is up, down, roll, hit. A compleletley different image to appear ontop of the current button so the user knows what tool is in use while they are using it..

What would be the easiest way to do this with AS3, the timeline and use of movie clips?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You want to define your button as an instance of SimpleButton, then set the images directly.  Kind of like this:

```
var clearBtn:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();
clearBtn.upState = mc2;
clearBtn.overState = mc2a;
clearBtn.downState = clearBtn.upState;
clearBtn.hitTestState = clearBtn.upState;
```

Which I took from a similar question / answer posed [on the adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1282509).

Answer (score 0):

If you have these buttons as MovieClips - just change their type to Button in the library. Each button has four keyframes 1- default state, 2 rollover, 3 hit and 4 hit area.

That's the easiest solution without coding.